# Can GHC executables share runtime code?

Tags: haskell, optimization, runtime, ghc

Say someone want to recreate standard POSIX executables (cat, dd, ls ...) in Haskell. But executables that GHC generates all include runtime code. So, is it possible

- to share runtime code between several executables and make them smaller and faster to load?
- to use one garbadge collector per system? (not sure if this is good optimisation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- People have created typical unix utilities in Haskell, just look at [Linspire](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/realworld/linspire.html).
- You can use shared libraries with Haskell, or more specifically, with GHC.  Even the RTS can be a shared library.
- You can not have one garbage collector instance collecting for multiple processes (if that is what you ment).  This also would not be a good idea seeing as the currently implemented GC schemes must stop the mutator threads during collection.

Comment: For excellent entertainment (provided you speak Japanese) follow the link to the "Linspire OS site"... the Freespire one is somewhat more boring, as it's merely dead.

Comment: Right, Freespire and Linspire were born out of the much hyped `Lindows` OS (~2005?).  It is unfortunate, but not surprising, that the projects have since died - I don't imagine it's easy to sell a Linux distribution to end-consumers.